# How to store array in node object chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am reading a file inside a ruby_block in chef. I am storing each line in an array. I want them to be accessible anywhere within my chef recipe, so i did a bit of research and found out that i can use node object.

The problem is whenever i am using the node object its storing the last line only and not each line.

This is my code. Any suggestions?

```
ruby_block "name" do
  block do
    CSV.foreach('/tmp/users.txt') do |row|
    node['username']=row
    end
  end
  action :run # see actions section below
end
```

Okay so this is my code now.

```
ruby_block 'name' do
  block do
    CSV.foreach('/tmp/users.txt'){ |row| node.run_state['username123'] |= [row] }
  end
end 

directory "/sftp/#{node.run_state['username123']}/incoming" do
  action :create
  recursive true
end
```

and my outputs of chef-run comes up to be.

```
directory[/sftp//incoming] action create 
- create new directory /sftp//incoming
```

Answer (score 2):

SEE new answer (didn't want to confuse anyone with the comments)

Two choices.  If you really want to use the node, the you need to use an array, which you are not.

```
ruby_block 'name' do
  block do
    CSV.foreach('/tmp/users.txt'){ |row| node['username'] |= [row] }
  end
end
```

But, unless you want that info to be stored in the node object on the server, I'd suggest you actually store it in the run_state

```
ruby_block 'name' do
  block do
    CSV.foreach('/tmp/users.txt'){ |row| node.run_state['username'] |= [row] }
  end
end
```

This still makes it accessible to the rest of your recipes, but it keeps it out of the node object which will be sent to the chef server at the end of you run.

Comment: Hi,

The file is having some content but my node object comes to be empty. I am not sure what is happening. Can you recomend anything?

Comment: did you try the code I posted? You can also add a Chef::Log.warn message inside the ruby block to make sure you're properly parsing the file.

Comment: Yes i have used your code. This is what my code looks like.

`ruby_block 'name' do
  block do
    CSV.foreach('/tmp/users.txt'){ |row| node.run_state['username123'] |= [row] }
  end
end`


`directory "/sftp/#{node['username123']}/incoming" do
  action :create
  recursive true
end`








This is my output. I am not sure what wrong i am doing.
 `directory[/sftp//incoming] action create
    - create new directory /sftp//incoming`

Comment: Two things, first, please put the new code in the question, not a comment.  Reading code in comments is close to impossible.  Second, run_state and node are different animals.  To access run_state you need to do `node.run_state['name']`, not `node['name']`.  If you update the question with the new code, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have updated the question. Really appreciate your help on this. I know i am doing something silly but can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

OK, so your problem is due to the two-stage nature of Chef.  You are declaring your directories in the "compile" stage, but you try to do so with data from the inside of your `ruby_block`, which doesn't execute until the second stage.  If your CSV file is not put into place by chef, you could do this:

```
# notice this is not in a ruby block
CSV.foreach('/tmp/users.txt'){ |row| node.run_state['username123'] |= [row] }

node.run_state['username123'].each do |next_file|
  directory "/sftp/next_file/incoming" do
    action :create
    recursive true
  end
end
```

If the CSV file is put into place by chef, you'll need to force it to be there before the CSV parsing runs.  You *MIGHT* be able to do this:

```
cookbook_file 'mycsv file' do
  ...
end.run_action(:create)
```

at some point prior to your CSV parsing.  If that's not an option (for any of several reasons) then you would need to get fancier.  At this point you would probably be best-off creating an LWRP.

Comment: Great thanks. I was already using the method you mentioned. Rather than storing them in the node object i am using a ruby array. I am using a template file to create the csv file. 

The only thing i was missing was the .run_action(:create) as i was not able to parse the file on the first chef run.

That worked